# passing ajax variables to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar and I want to use the start variable from the "select" callback as a PHP variable.

This is my JavaScript:

```
select: function(start, end) {
  $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD '));
  $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD '));
  $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');

  var start = val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD ')) ;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {start:start},
  });
},
```

This is my PHP script :

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['start']) ){
  $start = $_POST['start'];
  echo json_encode($start);
}
else echo "string";
?>
```

This is my HTML input:

```
<input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
```

but I get "string" as a result.

Comment: `but i get String as a result` - you mean `string` not `String`, right?

Comment: Try adding `value="test"` to that `<input>`

Comment: and your question is .. ?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i mean string thats mean that there is not post['start']

Comment: @omaymauchiha what string? All values are string when posted

Comment: @treyBake <?php
if( isset($_POST['start']) ){
 $start =  $_POST['start'];
echo json_encode($start);


}else echo "string";
?>

Comment: ahh console.log $_POST before your condtional, see what is actually posted

Comment: @treyBake Notice: Undefined index: start in E:\wamp\www...

Comment: it's a bit unclear, but I would guess your issue is that you appear to be sending the AJAX request as soon as your page is loading (since it's directly inside a `<script>` tag). But at that time your "start" input has no text in it, so no value is sent to the server. Do you really want to wait until there is a value in the input? What event in your page should cause the AJAX request to be sent? e.g. should the user click a button, maybe? (And what does any of this have to do with fullCalendar??)

Comment: @ADyson when i select dates in fullcalendar its automatecly give me the start date and the end date so the input is not empty

Comment: In the HTML you showed above, the input is empty. Since your document.getElementById() and AJAX code runs **immediately** when the page loads, I think there will not be time for any other code to populate the input before you try to read its value. (And fullCalendar does not populate this field automatically itself, you must have some extra custom code for doing that?)

Comment: P.S. Why do you need any of this stuff anyway? If you are trying to fetch events by this method, you don't need to do it like this. fullCalendar can send an AJAX request to your server automatically to get events, and will automatically send the start and end dates in that request as well. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . I mentioned this yesterday in your earlier question! Did you take a moment to read the article?

Comment: @ADyson i read this documentation but i did not understand how to use it to get the start as a php variable

Comment: `  select: function(start, end) {

                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD '));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD '));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
            },
`

Comment: @ADyson this methode give me the start and end date automaticly

Comment: Ok let's clarify something important: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to send your server data about a new event, or are you trying to fetch data about existing events?

Comment: i need to use the start and end date selected to check avaibalety like this : $sql = "SELECT * FROM chambre WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id_chambre FROM reservation_client where start <= selected.end AND end >=selected.start)";

Comment: can you answer my question directly please? Which one of the two things I mentioned are you trying to do? Are you trying to send the server information about a new time the user has chosen? Or are you trying to retrieve a list of existing events from the database, to display in the calendar?

Comment: @ADyson okay i need to use the selected dates to check avabalety

Comment: Ok so that other link I gave you was about fetching existing events, so yes you can ignore that. It wasn't clear what you were actually trying to use these dates for, so thankyou for clarifying.

Comment: If you are trying to send the server information about new dates the user has chosen, then you need to wait until the user has finalised their selection and completed all the data in the form, before you can send your request. I guess maybe they press a button in your modal when they have completed this? If so, then you need to make your AJAX call run when the button is pressed. Right now (as I mentioned previously), your AJAX code runs as soon as your page is loaded, which is no good for this situation. Do you understand how to handle a button click event in JavaScript?

Comment: Right, so when is the moment that you want to check the availability? Is it as soon as the user selects the date? If so then put the AJAX request inside your `select: function(start, end) {...` callback, so that it runs after the user has chosen the dates, and at the same time that you are populating the modal. The button was just an example of a common way to do it. The important point was to understand that you need to delay the sending of the request until the necessary data is available. As long as you grasp that concept, the detail of **exactly** how/when you send the request is up to you

Comment: @ADyson thats what i do i put my ajax request inside the select: function(start, end) {...  but there is not a post['start] this is why it give me string

Comment: Please edit the question to show your current `select: ` function, so I can see exactly how you changed your code. I can't guess what precisely you might have done wrong. It will be some the small detail, no doubt.

Comment: As I mentioned, please **edit your question**. Code in comments is really hard to read. The "edit" button is just under your question, near the little blue tags. That way you can format the code properly so it's easy to read, and also so it's obvious to anyone reading the question in future. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have managed to format your code when you first posted the question, so maybe just repeat whatever you did then. You can get further help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Anyway. I see no reason why this code would now fail to send a correct value to your PHP. Have you checked in your browser's Network tool to watch the AJAX request, and see what value is actually being _sent_ in the request body?

Comment: From my point of view the only missing piece of the jigsaw is the `val()` function...I don't know what this does. Maybe it does not return a valid value, that could be part of your issue?

Comment: Also I don't know how you are seeing the output of the PHP (to know that it returns "string"), since your AJAX code doesn't have any callback to handle the returned value? Are you looking in your browser's Network tool for this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Echo the `$['start'`] so you see what it returns first.
you can format strings in php to date using the following formats

```
$time = strtotime('10/16/20019');

$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
echo $newformat;
```

or in your case
$time = strtotime($_POST['start']);

```
$newformat = date('Y-m-d',$time);
echo $newformat;
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: start ` thats the problem

Comment: This means the post didnt hit your PHP script....Try this to test if the the post is hitting the script with the 'start' param

`if(isset($_POST['start'])){
   echo "HI";
}
else { echo "no";}`

Comment: The error is from the ajax call dem, lemme look into it, give a a sec

Answer (score -1):

Your ajax block is missing the post url.....code should look more like this

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'urltopage.php', 
    data: { start: start },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Submitted to php');
    }
});
```

Comment: but i dont need a url i'm in the same page

Comment: console.log the variable `start` in the success param in ajax lets see what it returns

Comment: and what html element do u want to pass the formated date to, lets see the html element in code here please